# How do I merge rows of data in python?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a CSV with rows of data in the rows:

**Data:**

jobID | industry | clicks

job1, healthcare, 20

job1, healthcare, 30

job2, medicine, 40

job2, medicine, 50

**Expected Output:**

job1, healthcare, 50

job2, medicine, 90

There are multiple jobIDs and each row represents a day. How can I concatenate the rows with the same jobID with the clicks being added? I'm using python with pandas.

I tried using the `pd.concantenate()` but there are so many rows of the same jobID so I'd have to write every row.

Comment: It seems need `df[df['jobID'] == df['clicks']`

Comment: @jezrael Will do thank you.

Comment: @jezrael I added the information, can you take a look at it. I want to be able to have it so that there's just one job, with all the clicks being added.

Comment: Use `df = df.groupby(['jobID', 'industry'], as_index=False)['clicks'].sum()`